# assigning items in a list to items in another list in python

Tags: python, list, loops

I have two lists.

```py
for row in self.json_data['athletes']:
    most_stats = row['categories'][1]['totals'][0:11]
f = [self.pts, self.fgm, self.fga, self.fgp, self.three_pm, self.three_attempted, 
     self.three_percent,
     self.ftm, self.fta, self.percent_ft, self.ast]
```

All the attributes are empty lists.

I want to write a loop that assigns every attribute to an index in most stats.
every index matches the index position of its attribute, meaning:

```
f[0] = most_stats[0]

f[1] = most_stats[1]

f[2] = most_stats[2] ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing:

```
f[0] = most_stats[0]
```

You are overwriting the value of `f` at index `0`, rather than updating the list referenced by `self.pts` with `most_stats[0]`.

So if the goal is to update `self.pts`, `self.fgm` and so on, you should iterate through `most_stats` with `f` using `zip` and assign to each referenced sub-list in `f` with the corresponding sub-list in `most_stats` in-place:

```
for i, j in zip(f, most_stats):
    i[:] = j
```

Comment: The loop will only work if the values of the attributes are lists.

Comment: Which is exactly what the OP explicitly states and wants.